# When I use a block in C++, will objects be copied or referenced?

Tags: clang, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++

Imagine this C++ code (which uses clang's blocks language extension).

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

std::async(^ {
  auto time = now;
  // ...
});
```

What will be the type of `time`? Will it be `decltype(now)` or `decltype(now)&`? If it's the latter, how can I make sure it's copied before the block runs?

Comment: What is that `^`? How are you capturing `now` in your lambda expression?

Comment: This is Objective-C++, not C++. Retagged.

Comment: @mfontanini it's a language extension from clang.

Comment: @Radek'daknok'Slupik Well, from Apple and included in clang, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object is copied, and its type is `decltype(now)`, as per the [block language specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.txt).

> Stack-local objects are copied into a Block via a copy const constructor.  If no such constructor exists, it is considered an error to reference such objects from within the Block compound statements.